# forever --watchDirectory for every 5min

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

Is there any possibility to run forever npm package watch for every 5min. Please suggest any solution for this problem.

forever npm package option to run `--watchDirectory` and `--watch` but look for watching in a interval.

And restarting all process how are start only child process if any files changes happen in a directory or file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [nodemon](http://nodemon.io/).  It offers a [`--delay` option](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#delaying-restarting) that waits a period of time after a change is detected before restart to prevent churn in case multiple files are changing.